# Discord NET C# Roles list

Tags: c#, discord.net

I tried to make a list of roles and the list is messy, if possible someone will tell me according to what the list is arranged.
Good Day:)

This is what I tried and it sends me a message of the name a random role:

```
foreach(var roles in Client.GetGuild(Guild).Roles)
{
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Role name: {0}",roles.Name));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *the list is messy*? Can you please clarify? Also, your code example is insufficient to recreate the problem - help us help you by providing a complete example - what is `Client` in your code? (http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion)

Comment: By the way, quick check of the docs and source code for Discord.NET reveals that `SocketRole : IRole`, which is returnded by `Guild.Roles` is an `IComparable<IRole>`, based on `Role.Position`, which is a "position relative to other roles in the same guild".

Comment: Assuming that messy means un-ordered,  the suggestion above to order by `Position` would be your  best option.

Answer (score 2):

Just use that

```
 List<SocketRole> roles = channel.Guild.Roles as List<SocketRole>;
```

Answer (score -1):

For list role in a guild with windows form software

```cs
                ulong idg = Convert.ToUInt64(textbox1.text);
                var guildid = _client.GetGuild(idg);
                foreach (var role in guildid.Roles)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(role.Name);
                }
```

For discord bot

```cs
        [Command("listrole")]
        public async Task listRoleasync()
        {

            foreach (var role in Context.Guild.Roles)
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(role.Name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: How is this different from what the OP has?